# Replacing a javascript function inside an object using GreaseMonkey

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, overriding, tampermonkey

I am having some troubles finding a way to replace a javascript function that is defined as a property of an object. I had googled it for 2 days and looked at all the questions in stack overflow that are related to overriding a function with javascript, but none of the solution worked.
I currently have a webpage (http://gefs-online.com if it helps), and there is an object called "multiplayer" that is declared somewhere like that:

```
var multiplayer = window.multiplayer || {};
```

After that, there are some properties under multiplayer that are declared like that:

```
multiplayer.nbUsers = 0;
multiplayer.users = {};
multiplayer.visibleUsers = {};
multiplayer.minUpdateDelay = 500;
multiplayer.updateTimeout = null ;
multiplayer.hearbeatTimeout;
multiplayer.hearbeatLife = 9000;
multiplayer.userLife = 10000;
multiplayer.userHalfLife = 4000;
multiplayer.mapUpdatePeriod = 10000;
multiplayer.myId = '';
multiplayer.lastRequest = null ;
multiplayer.lastRequestTime = 0;
multiplayer.localTime = new Date().getTime();
multiplayer.farVisibilityRange = 10000;
multiplayer.lowVisibilityRange = 1000;
multiplayer.nearVisibilityRange = 20;
multiplayer.chatMessage = '';
multiplayer.chatMessageId = 0;
multiplayer.on = false;
multiplayer.started = false;
multiplayer.callsignPlacemarkAltitude = 4;
multiplayer.updateFunctions = [];
multiplayer.init = function() {};
```

The function I'm willing to override is multiplayer.loadModel() that is declared like that:

```
multiplayer.loadModel = function(oPlayer, oData, lod, callbackFunction) {
    ... //the code of the function
};
```

Now I want to override that function using GreaseMonkey, but without success. I can't use the regular method of unsafeWindow - because it is not working, and even if it worked, only firefox supports it.

I have read all the questions that are related to the subject, but still didn't find anything, so please don't rate it down.

Thanks to whoever helps me.

**UPDATE:** I tried again implementing the unsafeWindow like that:

```
unsafeWindow.multiplayer.loadModel = function (oPlayer, oData, lod, callbackFunction) {
    console.log ("loadModel()");
}
```

But it only says : "ReferenceError: unsafeWindow is not defined"

Comment: you say `It's not a global` ... window.multiplayer **IS** global by definition

Comment: Oh, you are correct. that is my mistake - I'll fix that. Still, the normal ways of doing that are not working for me.

Comment: Is loadModel set with `Object.defineProperty`, because if it is, you can't overwrite is because it's protected by `writable, configurable false`.

Comment: there are many 'gotchas' when working with unsafeWindow - some js functionality you take for granted does not work the same in the context of greasemonkey

Comment: @Mouser, there is no defineProperty there. it is defined as you can see here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, the ==UserScript== definition was wrong.
When using Greasemonkey (Firefox), it should be like this:

```
// @grant        none
```

But when using Tampermonkey/ViolentMonkay (Chrome/Opera) it should be like this:

```
// @grant        unsafeWindow
```

Answer (score -1):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Multiplayer
// @version      1
// @description  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31831816
// @include      http://gefs-online.com/map.html*
// @grant        none
// @run-at       document-end
// ==/UserScript==

var interval = setInterval(function () {
    if(window.multiplayer && window.multiplayer.loadModel) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        window.multiplayer.loadModel = function (oPlayer, oData, lod, callbackFunction) {
            console.log("loadModel()");
        };
        console.log("multiplayer.loadModel changed to: ");
        console.log(window.multiplayer.loadModel.toString());
    }
}, 1000);
```